# Right Click on Tray Icon in Windows 10 with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, windows-10, system-tray

In Windows 7, I had an AutoHotKey script that would automatically Right-Click on a tray icon.

```
#Include %A_Scriptdir%\TrayIcon.ahk
TrayIcon_Button("CCC.exe", "R")
```

Which used the TrayIcon.ahk library from [FanaticGuru's post](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=9186#p9186).

This worked just fine on Windows 7, but no longer works on Windows 10.

Is there a way to right click on a TrayIcon in an AutoHotKey script on Windows 10?

Here is the TrayIcon_Button function from the library. I refrained from posting the entire library since it is fairly long.

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Function .....: TrayIcon_Button
; Description ..: Simulate mouse button click on a tray icon.
; Parameters ...: sExeName - Executable Process Name of tray icon.
; ..............: sButton  - Mouse button to simulate (L, M, R).
; ..............: bDouble  - True to double click, false to single click.
; ..............: index    - Index of tray icon to click if more than one match.
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TrayIcon_Button(sExeName, sButton := "L", bDouble := false, index := 1)
{
    Setting_A_DetectHiddenWindows := A_DetectHiddenWindows
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    WM_MOUSEMOVE      = 0x0200
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN    = 0x0201
    WM_LBUTTONUP      = 0x0202
    WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN    = 0x0204
    WM_RBUTTONUP      = 0x0205
    WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206
    WM_MBUTTONDOWN    = 0x0207
    WM_MBUTTONUP      = 0x0208
    WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0209
    sButton := "WM_" sButton "BUTTON"
    oIcons := {}
    oIcons := TrayIcon_GetInfo(sExeName)
    msgID  := oIcons[index].msgID
    uID    := oIcons[index].uID
    hWnd   := oIcons[index].hWnd
    if bDouble
        PostMessage, msgID, uID, %sButton%DBLCLK, , ahk_id %hWnd%
    else
    {
        PostMessage, msgID, uID, %sButton%DOWN, , ahk_id %hWnd%
        PostMessage, msgID, uID, %sButton%UP, , ahk_id %hWnd%
    }
    DetectHiddenWindows, %Setting_A_DetectHiddenWindows%
    return
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested it on Windows 10. It was not working for the icons hidden under overflow window, although it was working perfectly for the visible icons.

Update these three lines in `TrayIcon_GetInfo()` for a quick solution

```
For key, sTray in ["Shell_TrayWnd","NotifyIconOverflowWindow"]
SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
```

Replace them with

```
For key, sTray in ["NotifyIconOverflowWindow", "Shell_TrayWnd"]
SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
```

**Update:** To awesome users who have upgraded to Windows 1607, it is broken again :)

To make it work again in Windows 10 1607, first follow those last rules. After that replace these with:

```
SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
```

with

```
if ("Shell_TrayWnd" == sTray) {
    SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
} else if ("NotifyIconOverflowWindow" == sTray) {
    SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
}
if ("Shell_TrayWnd" == sTray) {
    SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
} else if ("NotifyIconOverflowWindow" == sTray) {
    SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%key%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
}
```

**Note:** I don't think any of these changes are backward compatible.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with Windows 10 1709. Any idea how to fix this? Maybe from the [latest version](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=9186#p9186) of the library as well?

Comment: @Otiel That's why I love the Windows update. I am going to update windows this weekend. Hopefully I will try to figure out a solution by monday.

Comment: @Otiel Hey I forgot to reply. I upgraded Windows and it's still working fine for me.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Thanks for letting me know, I'll try again. Could you please share the entire library code you're using?

Comment: Thanks, it works better with your version (I had a more recent version according to the header date). But it doesn't work for every software... Tried with `keepass.exe`, all good. Tried with `slack.exe`, it doesn't work, even though the AHK Window Spy displays `ahk_exe slack.exe` for the Slack window. :(

Comment: @Otiel How to run it? I copied the pastebin.com/jWkrKauS  in an test.ahk and ran it, but nothing happen.

Comment: @JinSnow This is a library to interact with tray icons (btw, I'm using a newer version that you can find on https://pastebin.com/1iSj6yUn). To simulate a click on a tray icon, you need to call the `TrayIcon_Button` function (check its signature, there are several arguments available - left click / right click...) in your `test.ahk` file.

Comment: Thanks! Runing you last code, with this at the end of my script does work `TrayIcon_Button("dimmer.exe","R",false, 1)` it even find it with a wrong index number! (Adding a msgbox at the end doesn't work because it opens and closes the menu very quickly)

Comment: @Otiel This library rocks!

Comment: As of Oct 2020, the TrayIcon.ahk library from FanaticGuru's post works with both Windows 7 and Windows 10 (version 1803) with no further modifications. Pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try the official method of running the AHK script as admin by adding this code to the beginning:

```
if not A_IsAdmin
{
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Requires v1.0.92.01+
   ExitApp
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it made no difference. The problem doesn't seem to be with the macro not having permission.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ... there is ... "an easier way" ???

"Back in the day" I used to use Sean's TrayIcons ...

I haven't felt like "deciphering" all the new/intricate scripts that (have) followed Sean's ...

So, I finally "focused" on some Trial&Error
based on [AHK Boards tmplinshi's Post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=67373)

Following tmplinshi's guide, I derived (that) I needed message code 40022 posted to (hidden) window (class) NirSoft_VolumouseMsg100-x64

So, the (simple/direct) coded-solution became/is:

```
DetectHiddenWindows ON
PostMessage, 0x111, 40022, , , ahk_class NirSoft_VolumouseMsg100-x64 ahk_pid %VolMpid%
DetectHiddenWindows OFF
```

I encountered one (little) "wrinkle" in that the above would not work for some (unknown) reason IF the script was displaying SplashText when doing the PostMessage ⁉️

I (have) found that tmplinshi's method can replace WinMenuSelectItem as well