# How to enable/disable Windows 10 battery saver in program?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm writing a small program to save my laptop's battery, and I can now switch between power schemes using `PowerSetActiveScheme`.

The next step is to control the battery saver in Windows 10. Though I can read the state of it using `GetSystemPowerStatus`, I can't find a way to enable/disable it programmatically. Are there any functions in Windows API to do this?

Comment: have you looked through: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: I can't find anything in the (English version) that article that would allow switching 'battery saver' to 'on'. FWIW, looks like you are not alone in this question:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8b1dbe33-d8fb-4be8-af53-0de13d288136/enabling-battery-saver-energy-saver-in-windows-10-via-win32-api?forum=powermanagement

Comment: It does take PowerSetActiveScheme().  But sure, you have no idea which particular scheme is the "good one".  Tinkering with the power schemes is one of the few ways that a computer manufacturer can make his machine "special", even though everybody uses the exact same components and exact same OS.  There is a better project out there.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you can do it Linux-way, by calling a system app named [`PowerCfg`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) through [`ShellExecuteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBATTTHRESHOLD 100
powercfg /setactive scheme_current
```

This means that the energy saver is activated even when the battery percentage equals 100%. `SUB_ENERGYSAVER` and its sub-GUID `ESBATTTHRESHOLD` are [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/energy-saver-settings).

Comment: That would work on Windows, if the battery saver feature is enabled.  I think the OP wants to know how to enable/disable the feature.

Comment: I wonder if setting the thresholds to 0 (using powercfg) is effectively the same as disabling the batterySaver feature

Answer (score 1):

@hidefromkgb's answer is pretty much correct. The only missing part is that to **disable** Energy Saver and prevent it from turning it on, you need to do:

```
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBATTTHRESHOLD 0
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBRIGHTNESS 100
```

If you do that, and go back to the control panel Battery Saver section, you will see that the first checkbox is now disabled (although it still shows 20% but it is grayed out so it should be ok). Also the second checkbox (lower screen brightness) will be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be out of luck. MSDN docs show no API through which the battery saver could be controlled. Examining SettingsHandlers_OneCore_BatterySaver shows that only GetSetting is exposed. [Even SetPowerState in WMI Win32_Battery is not implemented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) -- I know this is not exactly what you need, but it shows that Microsoft has not gotten around to exposing the battery-related functionality. At this point, instead of reverse-engineering the button click, your best bet is probably to emulate it with something like AutoHotKey, [however beware of the pitfalls with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814051/4454124).

Comment: I spent several hours looking at this the other day.  There's more than one way to set thresholds and control power levels, but no published means to enable/disable the feature.